# Nautilus popping up after inserting USB stick in KDE

Tags: linux, usb, debian

I am using Debian testing with KDE 4.6.5. However, when I insert my ubs stick, on top of the expected kde response I get a Nautilus window popping up (which is the Gnome file manager). How can I disable this?

Comment: Do you use nautilus for anything? Would you be OK to remove it?

Comment: @Simon, I actually use it for mercurial (there is a plugin for nautilus, but none for any native kde app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gvfs is Gnome virtual filesystem manager, but it should not be started 
under a KDE session unless you are/were running a Gnome service/program 
that requires its use.
Check the daemons that are started within your current KDE session or 
just close any instance of gvfs, save your current KDE session and choose 
that KDE starts a manually saved session to prevent the service being 
started on each login.

Comment: Yes, `gvfsd` is running. I have a suspicion that it was started by chrome, because there are chrome processes with pids immediately smaller and bigger. Will investigate further.